# How to process data in a list using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to iterate over 2 loops in a List using Java Stream.

```
public class ArrayStreams {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(2);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("i :" + list.get(i) + "J :" + list.get(j));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can i convert this code into Java Stream. Please help!

Comment: Why do you want to convert it into Java Stream?

Comment: I am converting all the code to Java 8 for better readability.

Comment: Why do you think streams would express this logic in a more readable way if you don't know how to write it?

Comment: not sure whether it's more readable to you or not but this is the equivalent --> `IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                 .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, list.size()).forEach(j ->
                         System.out.println("i :" + list.get(i) + "J :" + list.get(j))
                 ));`

Answer (score 6):

> How can i convert this code into Java Stream.

You should not use Streams for at least two reasons :

- you don't iterate all elements in the second loop, so you should skip the first element in the inner loop.
- and **above all** you use indexes of the list in your `println(`). Streams are not designed to maintain index of the streamed elements

Comment: agree with this answer, although if one wanted to maintain an index and at the same time be able to use the element at that index then using `IntStream.range` may be an option.

Comment: @Aominè  It is an option indeed but we cannot recommend it. That' s why, I said : "you should" and not "you cannot". Streaming on `int`s  rather than objects contained in the list and using two `foreach()` don't appear as a stream/functional way processing but looks like more to a unfortunate way to convert an imperative code to a stream.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is a 1:1 translation of the loop

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(i+1, list.size())
        .forEach(j -> System.out.println("i :"+list.get(i)+"J :"+list.get(j))));
```

You could also use

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .forEach(i -> list.subList(i+1, list.size())
        .forEach(o -> System.out.println("i :"+list.get(i)+"J :"+o)));
```

which would be the equivalent of

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for(Integer o: list.subList(i + 1, list.size())) {
        System.out.println("i :" + list.get(i) + "J :" + o);
    }
}
```

though it would be better to do

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Integer o = list.get(i);
    String prefix = "i :" + o + "J :";
    for(Integer p: list.subList(i + 1, list.size())) {
        System.out.println(prefix + p);
    }
}
```

reducing the redundant work.

A more declarative approach is

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
         .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i+1, list.size())
                                .mapToObj(j -> ("i :"+list.get(i)+"J :"+list.get(j))))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Unfortunately, the alternative with the reduced redundant work can’t be expressed as Stream operation easily, due to the lack of a simple-to-use pair type. One solution would be:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .mapToObj(i -> new Object(){ int index=i; String prefix="i :"+list.get(i)+"J :";})
         .flatMap( p -> list.subList(p.index+1, list.size()).stream().map(o -> p.prefix+o))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Obviously, that’s not more readable than the nested `for` loops…

Comment: Really fine code illustrating why whatever the way streams will produce a code more convoluted.